# Failed to installed Kali Linux 2020.2 on VirtualBox 6.1

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I tried installing Kali Linux with the exact instructions from [this page](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-kali-linux-on-virtualbox). Most of the other guides have almost the same set of instructions when it comes to installing Kali on VirtualBox, but unfortunately I am getting errors while installing Kali with my **Windows 10 version 1903**.

I've been browsing the web for hours and found out that this error has been asked by others, but all the solutions seem to be just increasing disk space which I have done, and had no luck getting it to work. The error messages and the error log are shown below.

First error:

```
Install the base system

Unable to install busybox 
An error was returned while trying to install the busybox package onto the target system.
Check /var/log/syslog or see virtual console 4 for the details.
```

Second error:

```
Install the base system

Installation step failed
 
An installation step failed. You can try to run the failing item again from the menu, or skip it and choose something else. The failing step is: Install the base system
```

Error log:

```
Aug 4 17:16:43 in-target: Last modification reported: Thu, 04 Apr 2019 06:01:20 +0000
Aug 4 17:16:43 in-target: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
Aug 4 17:16:43 base-installer: error: exiting on error base-installer/kernel/failed-package-install
Aug 4 17:19:22 main-menu[1476]: WARNING **: Configuring 'bootstrap-base' failed with error code 1
Aug 4 17:19:22 main-menu[1476]: WARNING **: Menu item 'bootstrap-base' failed.
Aug 4 17:19:45 main-menu[1476]: INFO: Modifying debconf priority limit from 'high' to 'medium' 
Aug 4 17:19:45 debconf: Setting debconf/priority to medium
Aug 4 17:19:46 main-menu[1476]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
```

Comment: Details please. At the very least, how much disk space have you allocated for Kali? Is your host Windows OS 32bit or 64bit? Which Kali install are you using?

Comment: @roaima Just wondering why any of those details would affect "Unable to fetch some archives...".

Comment: Ah. I can see the images now. They're impossible to read on a mobile device so I don't even try. Nevertheless it's quite possible that the system is (still) out of disk space

Comment: Please, don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are difficult to read, and the post will not be found if someone googles when having the same problem. Instead, copy-and-paste the text into your question using proper formatting.

Comment: I'd also check the networking.  Windows firewall might be interfering with VirtualBox networking or it may just not be properly configured.  The problem with this question is the actual error has been hidden.  We know it failed to fetch some packages but we don't know why.  That error should have been listed earlier in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Apparently, the problem was caused by the Hypervisor from Windows. The problem was solved by using the solution suggested by @Chook from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505775/debian-apt-packages-hash-sum-mismatch) Shout out to @Chook!!